# Symfony - EntityType select repeats the same option

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-3.3

Building a form in Symfony 3.3.4, and using `EntityType` to get a select list of objects.

For some reason, when I use a certain entity, the select list returns all the same options with the same id's, even though the database table contains rows with different ids and names.

```
$form->add('projectComplexity', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:ProjectComplexity',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'choice_value' => 'id',
    'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
    'label_attr' => array('title' => 'Project complexity associated with this project'),
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $v) {
        return $v->createQueryBuilder('v')->orderBy('v.name',' ASC');
    },
))
```

[image]

Using the same format for the add for other objects works normally.

Here's the full form type class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('productCategory', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:ProductCategory',
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
                    'label_attr' => array('title' => 'Category for this product'),
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $v) {
                        return $v->createQueryBuilder('v')
                            ->orderBy('v.name',' ASC');
                    }
                ))
            ->add('name',TextType::class)
            ->add('detail',TextType::class)
            ->add('description',TextareaType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('cols' => '80', 'rows' => '10')
            ))
            ->add('supportDescription',TextareaType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('cols' => '80', 'rows' => '10')
            ))
            ->add('isCircuit', CheckboxType::class,  array('required' => false))
            ->add('deliveryType', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:DeliveryType',
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'label_attr' => array('title' => 'Type of delivery for this product'),
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $v) {
                        return $v->createQueryBuilder('v')
                            ->orderBy('v.name',' ASC');
                    }
                ))
            ->add('projectComplexity', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:ProjectComplexity',
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
                    'label_attr' => array('title' => 'Project complexity associated with this project'),
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $v) {
                        return $v->createQueryBuilder('v')
                            ->orderBy('v.name',' ASC');
                    }
                ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product'
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_product_type';
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if say, in a Controller, you repeat that QueryBuidler query and dump the results?  Still the same thing?  Or do you see the different values?

Comment: Sorry for triviality, but have you checked values you have in DB? Cuz it looks just okay.

Comment: Could you post your full form type?

Comment: Completely reasonable thought, Artur..  I did check and confirm that the DB contains different rows.  The curious thing is the select contains both the same ID and VALUE for each of the three options.

Adding the full form type into the original post.

Comment: Haven't resolved this yet.  One thing that's odd is if I add more rows to the table, it returns the right number of results, but they all show the same result with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on here.  It was a configuration issue with the ProjectComplexity entity that was the result of reverse engineering it's ORM annotation configuration from the database.

I finally noticed in the ProjectComplexity entity class, the id PK was BOOLEAN:

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="boolean")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

I had generated this entity using the reverse engineering method described on the Symfony website, and looking at the column definition in the database, the id column in that table was tinyint(3).   Which I can only assume the reverse engineering converts to boolean by default.

Once I changed the annotation to use integer, this worked as expected:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```